# How to make info-window of a marker in google-map to be responsive?

Tags: html, css, google-maps-react

So, I have been trying to use google-maps and fill my data with marker and show info-window.

For reference see img

[image]

But, my goal is to make the page responsive also, i have got many thing done but making infowindow resposnive is a prob.

My goal is to show info-window full screen upon click event. But currently its a stupid.

See img for reference

[image]

So, how to make my infowindow to show full screen upon click.

Thanks and appreciate your help.

EDIT:
my code

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
  import DRINKING_WATER_PUMP from './pins/strop3.png'
  import ROOFTOP from './pins/strop2.png'
  import IRRIGATION_PUMP from './pins/strop1.png'
  import PATVAN from './pins/strop5patvan.png'
  import MINIGRID from './pins/strop4.png'
  import farmer from './pins/user.png'
  import axios from 'axios'
  import config from './config.js'
  import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
  const mapStyles = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position:'relative',
    display: 'flex', 
    flexFlow: 'row nowrap', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
  };

  class MapList extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.markersRendered = false;
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
      if (JSON.stringify(this.props.places) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.places) && this.markersRendered) {
        return false;
      }
      this.markersRendered = true;
      return true;
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <span>

          {
            this.props.places.map((marker, index) => {
              let assetType=marker.assetType
              let icon={
              url:'' ,
              anchor: new this.props.google.maps.Point(12,23),
              origin: new this.props.google.maps.Point(0,0),
              scaledSize:  new this.props.google.maps.Size(20,20)
              }
              switch(assetType){
                case 'PATVAN':icon.url=PATVAN; break;
                case 'MINIGRID':icon.url=MINIGRID; break;
                case 'IRRIGATION_PUMP':icon.url=IRRIGATION_PUMP; break;
                case 'DRINKING_WATER_PUMP':icon.url=DRINKING_WATER_PUMP; break;
                case 'ROOFTOP':icon.url=ROOFTOP; break;
                default: break;
              }
              return (
              <Marker {...this.props} key={index} assetId={marker.assetId} assetType={assetType} icon={icon} position={{lat: parseFloat(marker.lat), lng: parseFloat(marker.lng)}}  />
              )
            })
          }

        </span>
      )
    }
  }

  class MapContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          showingInfoWindow: false,  //Hides or the shows the infoWindow
          activeMarker: {},          //Shows the active marker upon click
          selectedPlace: {'owner':{}}          //Shows the infoWindow to the selected place upon a marker
        };
        this.onMarkerClick=this.onMarkerClick.bind(this)
        this.onClose=this.onClose.bind(this)
      }
    onMarkerClick(props, marker, e){
      let url;
      switch(props.assetType){
        case 'PATVAN':url=config.patvan; break;
        case 'MINIGRID':url=config.minigrid; break;
        case 'IRRIGATION_PUMP':url=config.irrigation; break;
        case 'DRINKING_WATER_PUMP':url=config.drinkingwater; break;
        case 'ROOFTOP':url=config.rooftop; break;
        default: break;  
      }
      axios({
        url:url,
        method:'POST',
        data:{
          assetId:props.assetId
        },
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then((res)=>{
        if(res.data.data!==null){
          let data=res.data.data
          data['assetType']=props.assetType
          this.setState({
            selectedPlace: data,
            activeMarker: marker,
            showingInfoWindow: true
          });
        }
        else if(res.data.error!==undefined){
          if(res.data.error.errorCode===153){
            window.location.href='../login.html?redirect=dashboard';
          }
          else{
            Swal({
              type: 'error',
              title: 'Oops...',
              text: res.data.error.errorMsg,
            })
          }
        }


      })

    }
    onClose(props) {
      if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
        this.setState({
          showingInfoWindow: false,
          activeMarker: null
        });
      }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Map id="map"
          mapTypeControl={false}
          gestureHandling= {'greedy'}
          zoomControl= {false}
          streetViewControl={false}
          fullscreenControl={false}
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={5}
          style={mapStyles}
          initialCenter={{
           lat: 21.5937,
           lng: 78.9629
          }}
        >
          <MapList google={this.props.google} places={this.props.datapins} onClick={this.onMarkerClick} />

          <InfoWindow className="infoWindowCard"
            pixelOffset={new this.props.google.maps.Size(185,310)}
            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
            onClose={this.onClose}
            // disableAutoPan={true}
          >
            <div style={{'overflow':'hidden'}}>
            {this.state.selectedPlace.owner.image!=='NA'&&this.state.selectedPlace.owner.image!==null?(

              <img src={this.state.selectedPlace.owner.image} alt='farmer' className="infoWindowImg"/>
              ):(
              <img src={farmer} alt='farmer' className="infoWindowImg"/>
              )}
              <h4 className="infoWindowName" style={{'maxWidth': '262px'}}> {this.state.selectedPlace.owner.name} </h4>
              <h6 className="infoWindowName"> Customer ID: {this.state.selectedPlace.id} </h6>
              <div>
              <ul className="infoWindowDetail">
                <li>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <i className="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                    <span>Installed on {this.state.selectedPlace.dateOfInstallation}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <i className="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                    <span>{this.state.selectedPlace.owner.block}</span>
                    <p>{this.state.selectedPlace.owner.district}, {this.state.selectedPlace.owner.state} </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <i className="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                    { this.state.selectedPlace.assetType==='IRRIGATION_PUMP' &&
                      <div>
                      <span>Irrigation Pump <b>{this.state.selectedPlace.pumpCapacity} {this.state.selectedPlace.powerType} {this.state.selectedPlace.pumpType}</b></span>
                      <p>Solar Panel Capacity {this.state.selectedPlace.panelRating} </p>
                      </div>
                    }
                    { this.state.selectedPlace.assetType==='MINIGRID' &&
                      <span>Minigrid <b>{this.state.selectedPlace.assetName} </b></span>

                    }
                    { this.state.selectedPlace.assetType==='PATVAN' &&
                    <div>
                      <span>Patvan <b>{this.state.selectedPlace.pumpCapacity} {this.state.selectedPlace.powerType} {this.state.selectedPlace.pumpType}</b></span>
                      <p>Solar Panel Capacity {this.state.selectedPlace.panelRating} </p>
                      </div>
                    }
                    { this.state.selectedPlace.assetType==='DRINKING_WATER_PUMP' &&
                    <div>
                      <span>Drinking Water Pump <b>{this.state.selectedPlace.pumpCapacity} {this.state.selectedPlace.powerType} {this.state.selectedPlace.pumpType}</b></span>
                      <p>Solar Panel Capacity {this.state.selectedPlace.panelRating} </p>
                      </div>
                    }
                    { this.state.selectedPlace.assetType==='ROOFTOP' &&
                    <div>
                      <span>Rooftop</span>
                      <p>Solar Panel Capacity {this.state.selectedPlace.panelRating} </p>
                    </div>
                    }

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div className="portal">
                <span>Visit portal</span><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={ "../all_rms/rmspage.html?ID=" + this.state.selectedPlace.id } ><i className="fa fa-external-link-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
      );
    }
  }

  export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'MYAPI'
  })(MapContainer);
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Hi Gaurav - can you add the minimum amount of code required for us to duplicate your issue and help you?

Comment: added code for clarification

Comment: Try using `vw` units instead of `%` in your width and height.

Comment: @MarkE hi, can u calrify where ?